# Nested _for: for: if not:_ not working as expected

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a list of names

```
import random

nameList = ['BOB', 'JOE', 'DAN', 'CHRIS', 'JAMES']
randList = []
removeList = ['JOE', 'CHRIS']

for i in range(20):
    randInt = random.randint(0, 4)
    randFloat = random.uniform(0, 4)
    randList.append(nameList[randInt] + '_' + str(randFloat))

# print(randList)
```

and I am able to print out a new list comprising only the items that contain the strings  in `removeList` :

```
for name in nameList:
    for item in randList:
        if name in item:
            print('Hello ' + name + ' • ' + item)
```

However, I am attempting to do the **opposite**: print out a list of items that ***do not*** contain the strings from `removeList`

Why are the following attempts not resulting in my anticipated results (and what is the most efficient way to get desired results):

```
for name in nameList:
    for item in randList:
        if not name in item:
            print('Hello ' + name + ' • ' + item)
```

**or**

```
for name in nameList:
    for item in randList:
        if name in item:
            pass
        else:
            print('Hello ' + name + ' • ' + item)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for item in randList:
    for name in nameList:
         if name in item and name not in removeList:
             print(name)
             break
```

If you invert your loops (iterate over `randList` first), you can `break` out of the inner loop when you find a qualifying name.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks.  However, I had previously tried to invert the order of the loops as you suggest (first iterating through ```randList```, however that took me no where.  What really did it from your script was the if statement ```if name in item and name not in removeList:```.  I still do not understand though—and would be grateful for any clarification—why my two proposed attempts did not work. Since I was able to do ```if name in item:...``` why did it fail with ```if not name in item:...```  Also, why does my ```pass, else:``` fail?

Comment: Your two attempts are logically identical: `if this: that` vs `if not this: pass; else: that` do exactly the same thing. Neither of those code blocks makes reference to `removeList` which you'll have to do to figure out if the name qualifies or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `any()` function.

```
for name in nameList:
    if not any(name in item for item in randList):
        print('Hello', name)
```

There's no `item` to print in this case, since none of the items match.

Your code prints all the non-matching items, but there still could be a matching item -- you can't tell until you go through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print([name for name in nameList if name not in removeList])
```

I'm a bit confused by what the randList is doing in your code if you're just trying to get a list of names that aren't in the remove list but are in the nameList? Could you perhaps provide an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You could just avoid putting names in the rand list that your not interested. So as you build the randlist only append the name if its not in the remove list

```py
import random

nameList = ['BOB', 'JOE', 'DAN', 'CHRIS', 'JAMES']
removeList = ['JOE', 'CHRIS']
randList = []
for _ in range(20):
    rand_name = random.choice(nameList)
    if rand_name not in removeList:
        randList.append(f"{rand_name}_{random.uniform(0,4)}")

for element in randList:
    print(f"Hello {element.split('_')[0]} • {element}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
HEllo DAN • DAN_2.6129066804909606
HEllo BOB • BOB_1.2555220335071193
HEllo JAMES • JAMES_2.528215786926702
HEllo JAMES • JAMES_2.6441433380568147
HEllo BOB • BOB_3.343545146025066
HEllo BOB • BOB_1.4079854325792525
HEllo BOB • BOB_0.7971949952849191
HEllo JAMES • JAMES_1.067955225004117
HEllo BOB • BOB_2.8990933365663545
HEllo JAMES • JAMES_1.1432812287737648
HEllo DAN • DAN_3.0836648897302616
```